# Fleet cart using middlewares in routes but i can not find any $routemiddleware in project...not even in kernel.php ...where can i find it?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.7, laravel-passport

Fleet cart using middlewares in routes but i can not find any $routemiddleware in project...not even in kernel.php ...where can i find it?

**Laravel Version : 5.7**

---

**Passport Version : 7.5**

---

**CMS : FleetCart**

---

Kernel.php

```
namespace FleetCart\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \FleetCart\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \FleetCart\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \FleetCart\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \FleetCart\Http\Middleware\RedirectToInstallerIfNotInstalled::class,
        \FleetCart\Http\Middleware\RunUpdater::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \FleetCart\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \FleetCart\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    ];
}
```

\Modules\Accounts\Routes\public.php

```
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('account', 'AccountDashboardController@index')->name('account.dashboard.index');

    Route::get('account/profile', 'AccountProfileController@edit')->name('account.profile.edit');
    Route::put('account/profile', 'AccountProfileController@update')->name('account.profile.update');

    Route::get('account/orders', 'AccountOrderController@index')->name('account.orders.index');
    Route::get('account/orders/{id}', 'AccountOrderController@show')->name('account.orders.show');

    Route::get('account/wishlist', 'AccountWishlistController@index')->name('account.wishlist.index');
    Route::delete('account/wishlist/{productId}', 'AccountWishlistController@destroy')->name('account.wishlist.destroy');

    Route::get('account/reviews', 'AccountReviewController@index')->name('account.reviews.index');
});
```

Where that middleware('auth') came from? there is not anyother kernel files not anyother middleware representations. nothing.....!!

Looking for help!

Comment: auth middleware is coming from the Laravel auth, it's Framework file and you should not edit this file. You can read more on this resource https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.html

Comment: if i create 'auth' in kernel again.... to user as 'auth:api' middleware for Laravel passport it uses ('auth' from laravel) how can i handle that? everytime want to validate my token it redirects me to the login page.. and all i want is to get my token valudated and get an 'auth()->user()'

Comment: but fleetcart is not using laravel's own 'auth' middleware it has an Modules\Core\Http\Middleware\Authenticate.php

`public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (auth()->check()) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        $url = url()->full();

        if (! $request->isMethod('get')) {
            $url = url()->previous();
        }

        session()->put('url.intended', $url);

        return redirect()->route('login');
    }`

Comment: hey @sahamnadeem were you able to solve this? if yes, how? I'm facing the same problem, trying to use `auth:api` but it redirects me to the login page, as seen from the Fleetcart's Authenticate module you are reference

Comment: I want to still continue using fleetcart for all my web's routes, but use also laravel's `auth:api` middleware for all my `/api/*` endpoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `auth` middleware is registered in the `Modules/Core/Providers/CoreServiceProvider.php` file.

Check the `registerMiddleware()` method.

Comment: how can I continue using fleetcart for all my web routes, but use also laravel's `auth:api` middleware for all my /api/* endpoints/? thanks!. Currently all requests are entering to the  `CoreServiceProvider` you're referencing here and therefore to Fleetcart's custom Auth mw

Answer (score 0):

To authenticate API with Fleetcart, you need to create an API specific middleware and register it under

```
Modules/Core/Providers/CoreServiceProvider.php
```

You will now have two middleware for authentication one for application auth and one for api auth

```
 'auth' => \Modules\Core\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
 'api' => \Modules\Core\Http\Middleware\APIAuthenticate::class,
```

Under your APIAUthenticate middleware class, perform your authentication check. for below I am checking request header if it contains a Bearer token then checking the db for user with the token.

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Core\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Log;
use Modules\User\Entities\User;

class APIAuthenticate
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure                 $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
    
        if ($request->header('Authorization')) {

            $key = explode(' ',$request->header('Authorization'));

            Log::info(json_encode($key));

            if(isset($key[1]) && !empty($key[1])){

                Log::info('key: '. $key[1]);

                $user = User::where('api_token', $key[1])->first();

                Log::debug('user', array($user));
                if(!empty($user)){
                   
                    return $next($request);

                    
                }else{
                    return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthenticated']);
                }
            }
        }else{
            return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthenticated']);
        }

        return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthenticated']);
    }
}
```